# выполнить запрос из нескольких таблиц в один результат

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
SELECT DATA_MAIN, SUMM, SUMMV, KOD, COMMENT_DATA 
FROM DOCS_P D 
WHERE D.DATADOC_PRIH BETWEEN '02.03.2021 00:00:00' AND '02.03.2021 23:59:59'
  AND (D.KOD_DOC = '020047' OR D.KOD_DOC = '020045')
UNION ALL
SELECT DATA_MAIN, SUMM, SUMMV, KOD, COMMENT_S 
FROM DOCS_B D 
WHERE D.DATADOC_PRIH BETWEEN '02.03.2021 00:00:00' AND '02.03.2021 23:59:59'
  AND (D.KOD_DOC = '020048' OR D.KOD_DOC = '020049')
```

Подскажите пожалуйста выполняю запрос и все работает но только если в запрос не добавлять `COMMENT_S` и `COMMENT_DATA`, иначе ошибка `Invalid command. Data type unknown`.

Comment: а такие поля есть в БД?

Comment: Да все поля 100 % есть

Comment: И если выполнять запрос по отдельности то данные приходят

Comment: а какой ти имеют поля COMMENT_DATA и COMMENT_S? одинаковый ли?

Comment: CHAR(30) CHARACTER SET WIN1251 COLLATE WIN1251 и VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET WIN1251

Comment: вот в этои и пробелма скорее всего. тип должен быть идентичен, включая длину

Comment: А если к примеру тип поля не возможно поменять, нельзя обойти этот момент ?

Comment: попробовать у минимального написать так `CAST(FIELD as CHAR(60))`

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо это помогло мне